# Beautifulsoup how to parse h2 and underlying h3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm new (started this afternoon) to parsing lxml so bear with me. I'm trying to parse a csv with super hero data with lxml markup with beautiful soup.
I want to get the text inside of two h2 tags Powers and Abilities & Weapons and Equipment

```
soup.find_all("h2")
 >> [<h2><strong>Origin</strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Creation</strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Character Evolution</strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Major Story Arcs</strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Powers and Abilities</strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Weapons and Equipment</strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Character Profile</strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Alternate Realities </strong></h2>,
 <h2><strong>Other Media</strong></h2>,
 <h2>Merchandising</h2>,
 <h2><strong>Depiction and the Iconic Costume</strong></h2>,
 <h2>Popular Recognition</h2>]
```

when I look at the next sibling of h2 (the text is in a h3 tag) for Weapons and equipment I only get one item something back (should be more). And when I change the header.text to Weapons and Equipment I get no results.

```
    for header in soup.find_all('h2'):
        if header.text == "Weapons and Equipment":
            nextNode = header.nextSibling
            print(nextNode.text)
            if nextNode is None:
                break
>> Lasso of Truth
```

The Powers and Abilities + Weapons do show up in the findall('h3') results (together with other stuff that I do not want)

```
soup.find_all("h3", text=True)
>> [<h3>Challenge of the Gods</h3>,
 <h3>First clash with Circe</h3>,
 <h3>The New 52</h3>,
 <h3>Meeting Zeus Other Children</h3>,
 <h3>Meeting First Born</h3>,
 <h3><strong>Superhuman Strength</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Superhuman Speed</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Invulnerability/Durability</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Flight</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Healing Factor</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Divine Wisdom</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Super Stamina/Agility</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Great Beauty </strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Enhanced Sense</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Other Assorted Divine Powers</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>God of War Powers</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Martial Combat</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Lasso of Truth</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Bracelets of Victory</strong></h3>,
 <h3><b>Royal Tiara</b></h3>,
 <h3><strong>The Invisible Plane</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Battle Armour</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Martial Weapons</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Magical Sword</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Sandals of Hermes</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Gauntlet of Atlas</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Earrings</strong></h3>,
 <h3><strong>Power Rings</strong></h3>,
 <h3>War suits (or uniform)</h3>,
 <h3>The Dark Knight Strikes Again</h3>]
```

I've been reading documentation the whole afternoon but haven't found examples that can help me. I really don't know how I should get these items. Help and explanation would be appreciated.

snippet of data

```
    h2>Powers And Abilities </h2><br /><br /><ul class="plain-list">
<li>Reality Manipulation - Wanda possesses the ability to manipulate reality         
based on how hard she "wonders". The full extent of this ability is unknown, 
but it is known that she once wondered two of her enemies into non-existence 
during a battle in Las Vegas, Nevada.</li> <li>Psionic Abilities -  The full 
extent of Wanda's psionic abilities is currently unknown, but has been shown 
to include Mental Telepathy, Telekinesis, and Empathy.   <br /></li> 
<li>Superhuman Intelligence - Wanda possesses superhuman intelligence, 
including perfect memory, and data analysis. According to Woo-Z Winks, this 
may cause a problem in battle, as Wanda allows herself to battle purely on 
instinct, while her mind becomes lost in some deep philosophical point.  <br 
/></li> <li>Superhuman 
Strength<br /></li> <li>Superhuman Speed<br /></li> <li>Superhuman Agility<br />
</li> <li>Superhuman Dexterity<br /></li> <li>Superhuman Reflexes<br /></li> 
<li>Superhuman Senses</li></ul><p> <br /> </p> <h2>Paraphenalia </h2>

     <h3><ins>Weapons</ins></h3><p><strong>Lasso of truth</strong></p><p>The 
original lasso, still in existence in</p><p><strong>Harmony and 
Charity</strong></p><p>Wonder woman bracelets, posses intelligence and are 
programed with battle strategies.</p><p><strong>Invisible 
spacecraft</strong></p><p>Wonder Woman carries a invisible
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example of the data you are trying to process, so *we* can see how it is structured, along with any code you use to process it.  Please read [mcve]

Comment: It's kind of hard to give an example. The data comes from the comicvine api (I assume they used a webscraper since the layout looks like a webpage). I only have a csv loaded in variable soup. So no help there as well

Comment: Please don't post images, just copy and paste then format like code.

Comment: added it like code ^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tis "navigate to siblings" approach is the best for this case. You'd better try to use a better selector.

By using the `soup.select` method you can use CSS selectors to match multiple tags:

```
for headers in soup.select('h2,h3'):
    if "THIS" in header.text or "THAT" in header.text:
        print(header.text)
```

CSS selectors are powerful and flexible. I suggest you to study a little bit more about it: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Hmm this doesn't return anything. If I add a print statement after the for loop it prints the headers. However after the header.text == I get nothing back

Comment: Since the text is inside a <strong> element, you can use a substring comparison. Check the update

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the update with the substring comparison. I can see that you edited your original response but the for loop in the OP doesn't work.

Comment: I can e.g. substitute h3 for strong and when i print the headers.text I see the text. I just get nothing back for the if "Weapons and Equipment" in header.text or "Powers and Abilities" in header.text:
        print(header.text)

Comment: It may be something related to String comparison in python... I'll thing of some hypothesis here.